# Can a Jewish Business Refuse to Serve Certain Customers?

Tags: halacha, current-events, business

There have been several recent court cases regarding Christian businesses that have refused to provide service to certain customers based on religious grounds.

Assuming secular law has no opinion (*dina demalchuta* does not apply), what are the Halachot of a Jewish-owned business refusing to serve certain customers?  Is is permitted?  Prohibited?  Required in certain circumstances?  Would it matter if the customer is Jewish?

For example, can\should\must a Jewish-owned florist refuse to provide flowers for a gay wedding  <sub>(to use the case that's been in the news recently)</sub> ?

Comment: Do you have any reason to think there should be any regulations here?

Comment: I don't know. That's what I'm asking.  If there are, and what they are.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33729/allowing-unmarried-homosexual-couples-into-a-hotel

Comment: I think doing business with idolators is much more likely to be forbidden than with people who are gay.

Comment: There is a business district in "upstate" New York that many of its stores are incorporated under a massively large Jewish organization. Leaving the ethical issue of the situation out of this discussion, I suppose in that context the stores could refuse entry as they are legally recognized as a division of a religious institution. Well documented in the media are several stores in Williamsburg, Brooklyn that gained some, in my opinion, misguided negative press for attempting to enforce a dress code.......

Comment: .....The complainants claimed such a dress code was specifically targeting the local Hispanic and hipster populations. No one seemed to acknowledge that many non-kosher, Christian owned restaurants have dress codes as well. So I guess, within the context of civil law, yes Shmuel, Jewish businesses can to a certain extent refuse doing business with whomever they choose. Halakhakally? Someone else will have to answer that.

Comment: One more thought. In recent years there have been israeli chief rabbis who specifically stated that Jews should not or cannot rent or sell property to Arabs. Since they are the halakhic experts in the sense they have the exclusive authority to set and enforce halakhic standards for the entire country or at least within their city, I suppose there is credence to the notion that Jews are permitted to refuse to sell to non-Jews under certain conditions.  Related to that, how about Jews refusing to purchase from certain groups? There has been a longstanding tradition for Ashkenazi Jews in.......

Comment: .......New York not to purchase German cars. (Sephardim don't appear to follow that new tradition). The fact that many Jewish stores in Brooklyn sell Hugo Boss (who manufactured uniforms for the nazis), German made appliances (including Braun) and use aspirin for headaches (Bayer) is a discussion for another post.

Comment: @JJLL - Sometimes, German products are the best quality, price or value in a certain product. Personally, I don't buy any of the 3 products that you mentioned, including Bayer aspirin (I have a headache, typing this, now...) I use Walgreen's aspirin. Cheaper and I like the color!

Comment: This is a very very broad question. The example you give is a florist's refusing to cater to a gay wedding; a comment already has mentioned doing business with idolators and another has mentioned a dress code, but even a simple no-shirt-no-shoes-no-service policy would fall in the scope of this question, as would a policy of refusing service to black people, or refusing to allow non-Jewish kids into your day school, or you name it.

Comment: @DanF. Personally, I buy German made products. If money were no object, I'd take a BMW or Mercedes ANYDAY over any American or Japanese car. As far as your headache is concerned, I have a definite bias here. I'd go to a Jewish doctor for sure :-)

Comment: @JJLL - I like Jewish doctors in general, but who do you think gave me the headache in the first place ;-)

Answer (score 1):

My wife used to co-own a lady's hat store. Since most of her clients were Jewish women, she would not allow any man into the store while women customers were in the store.

Religious reasons! Women had their head uncovered and a man could not see a woman's uncovered hair.

I can't say if she allowed men to buy a lady's hat when there were no women in the store. I think that was fine until a woman walked in to try on a hat. Then the man had to leave the store.

I asked a lawyer if this was legal, and he said this is absolutely legal according to local and state law.